# Too big file size of Reactjs application after building via browserify + reactify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I am trying to build my simple Reactjs application via browserify+reactify but see the error in console

> Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "http://localhost:8000/app.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".

```
//index.js size 5KB
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var CommentList = React.createClass({...});
//terminal
browserify -t reactify index.js > app.js //after that size more than 600KB
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: React and the React-DOM library are both very large when browserifying.  Try setting `NODE_ENV` to `production`, and build again.  This usually goes from ~650 KB to ~250 KB for me.

Answer (score 3):

In react/redux/webpack/babel build fixed this error by removing script tag type text/babel

```
<script type="text/babel" src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Into

```
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `NODE_ENV` environment var before running browserify like this:

```
NODE_ENV=production browserify -t reactify index.js > app.js
```

If the bundle file size is still too large, consider using [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2):

```
NODE_ENV=production browserify -t reactify index.js | uglifyjs -c > app.js
```